# Movie with a battle at a huge white castle with a long drawbridge?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie ~5-10 years ago that was sci-fi / fantasy in nature. One of the scenes included a huge white castle with a long drawbridge. There was an extensive fight scene involving this drawbridge and castle. I believe that there were also horses and ? goblins (maybe zombies???, or an opposing army of some sort).

It definitely wasn't LOTR - I just saw all six of them again to be sure.

I saw this movie via one of the online streaming services. It was most likely Amazon Prime. This scene was one important for the main character development (male). I recall that he liked to ride a horse. He might have been Black.

The war / battle scene involving this huge white castle with long drawbridge involved a huge number of enemies. They eventually overwhelmed the castle's defences and penetrated its walls. This led to the death of a lot of people hiding inside the castle.

The movie was in English. It was live action. The drawbridge was over water. I do not recall any dialogue.

There's a cool scene where the camera zooms into the castle from a distance. You get a sense of just how grand and huge this castle is.

The battle itself involved medieval weapons. Ballistas, ladders, etc. The enemy did break through into the castle and started to kill civilians indiscriminately.

Updated 5/15:

@Valorum mentioned the movie Krull. It looks interesting and something I will have to put on my watchlist. However, this movie was not Krull. I believe the main character was Black. The people in the movie were also normal humans - but I am not sure about the opposing army. This movie was also more modern than Krull - made in the late 90s or early 00's.

@JMERICKS mentioned Army of Darkness. I just saw the [trailer] and this isn't it either. This movie was more serious. It was also much more colorful and set in a more realistic tone. The premise was more "plausible", if you will.[1](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi2629239065?playlistId=tt0106308&ref_=tt_pr_ov_vi)

@Kristian - great thought. I looked at the Thor movies again but it definitely isn't a superhero movie. The main character is just a regular guy without any super powers.

@NKCampbell - Great movie! I added it to my movies to see. Unfortunately, that isn't what I was thinking of here. Definitely remember seeing a huge white castle.

Now, I could really be mixing up my movies here, but this guy might have been a postman delivering mail by horse... but I'm not sure now.

Updated 5/17:
More gritty, more realistic with much better CGI. I honestly was 100% convinced it was from the LOTR so watched all six movies again (extended editions). No Gandalf-like character - just a humble person who was in the right (wrong?) place at the right time. There's a scene where he is riding his horse into the castle. They then prepare for a war, which is basically the majority of the movie. I saw the movie 5-10 years ago, and the movie itself couldn't be older than the 1990s - more likely 2000s.

There were catapults, ladders, archers - oh, and I think they dropped a fire bomb from up above onto a bunch of enemies. I couldn't be thinking of that popular TV show Game of Thrones, right? I remember the undead storming the white walls in the north later in the series, but as best as I can recall, there wasn't a scene like what I am describing earlier in the series, right?

@skyjack
Also not D&D. This movie was definitely more "realistic". I really thought it was LoTR. Same cinematography. Same level of acting. Same polished special effects. Thanks for taking the time to look!

@RobertF
Not Harold and Kumar go to White Castle, but definitely a classic there :).

A couple more details - when the enemy does break through into the castle, there's another scene where the main character (and others?) run into some underground, poorly lit passageway. This is how they escape from the castle at the end. I swear this was a movie - but just to cover my bases, this isn't a scene out of The Walking Dead, is it??

Updated 5/26:
@skyjack I actually watched the Warcraft movies just to be sure. Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. Those aren't it either. The live action in this film was much more realistic and believable - just like LoTR. I appreciate you looking!

Updated 5/27:
I really appreciate everyone's response to this thread. I guess it's telling me that this movie is harder to find than I thought - and so I am glad I posted it here.

A few more details:
This was a post-modern, post nuclear holocaust type event. The castle was large, and the castle siege itself was sort of the main event. The main character escaped via an underground tunnel - they were not able to save the castle. This was not a historical or historical fiction type of movie. I don't recall for sure whether the enemy laying siege was fictional - but I do believe that it was something evil. Zombies? Goblins? Just another army? I am not sure. As I mentioned earlier, I *really* thought it was from LoTR, but as I have clarified, I watched the extended versions and it was not there.

The Walking Dead?? Was there a castle scene in there?

Truly appreciate everyone looking!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see the movie?  (Theatre, TV, streaming...)  I'm assuming since you thought it might be LotR that it's live-action; what language was it in?  Do you remember anything that was said?  Was the drawbridge over water?  Over a chasm?  Over lava?

Comment: Please check out [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) of possible details for story-id questions. Going through them can elicit even more details to [edit] in. Did you watch this in theatres? On TV? DVD? VHS? Laserdisc? Cartoon? Live action?

Comment: Big white castle. Krull?

Comment: Army of Darkness perhaps?

Comment: One of the Thor movies? Heimdall was played by Idris Elba, large whitish castle for Asgard, lots of battles, several on the bridge, though it wasn’t a draw bridge.

Comment: Great Wall (w/ Matt Damon?)

Comment: I can't remember where the climax of the Warcraft movie takes place, possibly in Stormwind. . .

Comment: Harold and Kumar Go to White Castle?

Comment: @RobertF - That was hilarious. When I did my google search to try to find this movie, that is literally the only thing that kept coming up, page after page...

Comment: bit of a longshot, but your description reminded me of the TV show, The Shannara Chronicles, season 2 had a siege with the enemy overrunning the castle and killing everyone with the heroes narrowly escaping through a tunnel, there was also a castle built on a dam with a long bridge over water, although I don't think that was the one that was sieged

Comment: I saw that it just got cancelled for season 3. Bummer. I will check it out on YouTube but my initial glance tells me that this isn't it. But you have nailed the scene!

Comment: My first thought was Willow, but I don't think either castle that gets besieged is especially 'white'...

Answer (score 11):

Possibly the film Jack the Giant Slayer from 2013. English Language live action film with a fantasy/medieval setting.

also

Large castle with long bridge
battle scene
trolls/giants attacking

watch the clip on youtube here...

Comment: lol. They should have had fifty of those repeating crossbows.

Comment: actually I am shocked at how bad the CG looks in this. When I first watched the clip I thought it was from a video game. also having just reread the question this now does not seem so close a match. maybe should have posted as a comment not an answer... oh well lets see what the reaction is...

Comment: Very interesting find. This is unfortunately not the movie (but I upvoted your response anyway :)). This is VERY close to what I remember, however. Big white castle, archers, other medieval weapons. Invasion into the castle. People escaping. But without the bad CGI. The movie I remember was more realistic, more gritty, and more "believable" if you will.

Comment: @FontFamily sorry it was not the one, as i said in my comment after i reread your question it did not seem like a good match. here is another option...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SnA2rv4ros dungeons and dragons from about 2000. Never seen it myself but stumbled across the trailer on YouTube this morning.

Comment: @FontFamily... one more for you to check out... World of Warcraft from 2015. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rxoz13Bthc

Comment: @FontFamily https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbCy4Ku4xWc

Comment: I think this movie came out with a knockoff, or maybe this was the knockoff? You know how like "Antz" and "A Bug's Life" came out at the same time? I can't find it but if this was close the sibling movie may be closer.

Comment: The video was taken down. See if you can find a still.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna go with. . .

The battle of Camelot scene from the series "Merlin"

I believe Arthur escapes when Morgana takes the throne, there's a battle on a drawbridge, a white castle, lots of fantasy elements. It is also available on Amazon Prime.

Comment: Wow. Very cool series. This is something I will have to put on my watch list. Unfortunately, this isn't it. What I remember was... darker. It was post-modern and in a world that had moved on. Stephen King elements - post nuclear war type stuff (I think!).

Comment: @FontFamily I get ya. Do you remember what kind of scale the castle zoom-in was? Was it a castle, or a kingdom? Like Gondor/Stormwind scale or more like hogwarts?

Comment: It was a huge castle - really grand view of it that zoomed in like via a helicopter or drone. Not a kingdom. It was like Gondor.

Comment: I awarded you 50 points not for the right answer (still haven't found the movie), but for the best movie suggestion... lol. Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

It could have been [*King Arthur: Legend of the Sword*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1972591/) from 2017. It includes a battle to take a large castle reached by a long bridge.

The first shot of the castle is at about 0:41 in the trailer, then more beginning around 1:53.

Comment: Well, if there is one thing I have discovered, this forum is a great way to get ideas on movies to watch. This movie looks like it belongs on my list. The cinematography is CLOSE. The castle is CLOSE. But it isn't the right movie. The one I remember was definitely more "end of the world" type stuff. It was not a historical or historical fantasy type of movie. It was based in the future, sort of like a post nuclear holocaust type film.

Answer (score 3):

Robin Hood 2010 has a pretty big castle battle scene. Not a very grand castle or a drawbridge though, but maybe the battle scene looks familiar.

Comment: Thanks for looking! This castle actually looks somewhat like what I remember - except the castle I am thinking of was larger. The army assailing the castle was also definitely evil - undead? Zombies? "Bad" people? The main character was inside the castle providing defense.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like The Chronicles of Narnia: Prince Caspian.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how this matches the description provided in the question?

Comment: I don't know if I'd characterise the Narnians as zombies or undead though?

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Might make it more interesting, though. :)

Comment: Another cool movie and I appreciate the suggestion. No minotaur in the movie I am thinking of. They also weren't able to storm the main gate right away. It was a protracted castle siege scene that was basically the main event. The main character escaped via an underground tunnel at the end - they didn't save the castle.

Answer (score 1):

Black Knight?
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0265087/

The two main characters are black, and there is a large white castle. Numerous fight scenes as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you include some matching pictures, or describe how it matches the question?